# Custom mix task in Phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When I run custom Mix task in my Phoenix app (I think it's not even related to Phoenix but still) that uses some external library (e.g https://github.com/knrz/geocoder) I get

```
** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
    :erlang.send(:geocoder_workers, {:"$gen_cast", {:cancel_waiting, #Reference<0.0.1.13074>}}, [:noconnect])
```

until I add

`Application.ensure_all_started(:geocoder)`

to the Mix task. So my question is why all my dependencies are not started automatically? Is it me who's doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, your application's dependencies are not started by default in a Mix task. They need to be started manually. The simplest way to start all of your application's dependencies is to call `Mix.Task.run("app.start")` (or `Application.ensure_all_started(:my_app)` if Mix is not available). With this, all applications listed in your `mix.exs` file will be started if they're not already running.

This is documented near the end of the [Mix Tasks](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/mix-tasks) page on the Phoenix Framework site:

> If you want to make your new mix task to use your application's
>   infrastructure, you need to make sure the application is started when
>   mix task is being executed. This is particularly useful if you need to
>   access your database from within the mix task. Thankfully, mix makes
>   it really easy for us:
>
> ```
> def run(_args) do
>   Mix.Task.run "app.start"
>   Mix.shell.info "Now I have access to Repo and other goodies!"
>   ...
> end
> ```

Comment: Documentation seems to have moved: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/phoenix_mix_tasks.html#creating-our-own-mix-tasks

Answer (score 3):

In Elixir 1.11 you can use the `@requirements` module attribute as described in the [docs for `Mix.Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html):

```
@requirements ["app.start"]
```

This is equivalent to calling `Mix.Task.run "app.start"` in your `run` function.